# Choosing a conference and a paper publishing house - is it only a student responsibility when cooperating with supervisor?

Tags: advisor

I wrote an article that was a conference paper with my supervisor. It is to be published online in Conference Proceedings Magazine. Just some of the few of the chosen articles are about to be published in an quarterly magazine which is more "prestigious" in my field with more points.

When I was on my 1st year of PhD (now Im on my 2nd) I informed my advisor I wanted to join a conference even without an oral  presentation but only with a written article. (just to test myself in the international academic environment). It was me who found this event but I was a bit *unsure* of the field, did not know which conference is worth to apply. My supervisor never offered other conference or paper possibilities. Only when he realised that this event was international he immediately wanted to join in.

I agreed and was happy. We split parts for 50% and that is how it was signed by us.
The challange for me is that he was never interested in theme and time of the event, organisers themselves, he did not even check their website, any information. The organisation sent many emails regarding the conference, articles, presentations but he never checked them. He told me I needed to be responsible for everything. So I was.

I made sure he knew the organisation, the academic stuff, article deadline and everything even though he never checked anything by himself. Whenever we met I was telling him about the conference and the deadline, organisation.

But when the article deadline was approaching he started calling me and asking me questions that made me uncomfortable and I was in a bit shock. He did not know that the conference articles were firstly published in Conference Proceedings Magazine and later only chosen ones in some *better, more prestigious magazine* by the same publishing. He did not know that those magazines were published only online and started slowly accusing me on choosing *bad* conference and *bad* publishing house. He thought that articles would be printed in a paper version of a magazine.

I gave him those information way before.

I just only want to know if its obligatory that only a 1st year PhD student is responsible for everything? Is it normal that the advisor does not know the publishing house and the conference organisers ?

The deadline was in march this year and of course I sent our article.I am just not sure about his attitude towards this situation. Please clarify this.

What are your suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: What stage of his career is he? Early career...winding down?

Comment: In my opinion he is in the middle of his career (not sure though). But I am his first PhD student with my colleague.  Before us,  he only supervised master degree students.

Answer (score 2):

There are both valid and invalid reasons for such behavior, but, for some advisors, putting the task on you could mean both trust and forcing you to get the experience that you will need in your career.

Normally, venue would be a joint decision for a joint paper, I hope. Some advisors would impose their will on you, though. Is that better or worse?

On the negative side, which you seem to be focusing on, (worst case) the person is just lazy and disengaged. Hopefully that isn't the situation here.

Midway between, you say that you are the one who found the venue and it might not have been known to him, even in the best of circumstances. So, he leaves it to you.

But it is, in fact, good experience and you will need that for a successful academic career.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I am a person who needs to have some 'solid' background for any task I do. And when I don't know I usually ask for help. In that situation I did not feel I had this confidence and a 'solid background'. I thought he would help me choosing a 'good' conference or paper. Actually my other pHd colleague who has different supervisor told me he was given all the instruction about his first conference and paper by his supervisor. So it was different. I thought that the 'first' - conference, paper or anything needed to be carefully checked by an advisor.